# Apple iMac Video Card Compatibility

Tags: video-adapter

I am repairing an iMac 27" , late 2009 model (EMC 2374), 2.8 gHZ.  It has a bad video card causing stripes on the screen and problems booting.  The video card is an AMD ATI Radeon HD 4850 Video Card.   This model is very hard to find and very expensive.  Does anyone know of any other compatible video cards for this model apple machine?

thanks